# Can I use one system in a dual boot as a sandbox to do insecure things?

Tags: dual-boot, security

If I make my computer dual boot, could I use one system to do whatever silly things I want like installing as Netflix, Spotify, Skype and so on? For example, if an attacker gained access to my "stupid" account would they also gain access to my "safe" account?

And, can I mess around and learn on Ubuntu on the account for stupidity without affecting the other account if I make some huge mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu for instance, then it is say'd to be fairly easy to get into the Windows partition and take a peek at the files present there.

Now when installing Ubuntu, there is an option during the install to encrypt your home-folder. This will give a lot more protection and make the Ubuntu install safer from any harm that might come from elsewhere.

And even without it, the files should be pretty safe. Overall, I don't belive it is so easy to gain access to a whole HDD via just software these days. You would really have to download the worst of the worst from the World Wide Internet for that.

Usually such problems occur, when someone gains access to your computer physically.

Also, I would rather make a VM Ubuntu installation if you want to really mess around with bad stuff. This way you can just delete the VM when needed and no problems will arise.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it suited your needs with the little tick mark right to my post.